# External JavaScript file not working - ReferenceError

Tags: javascript, html, referenceerror

So, I have this really weird error. I am trying to link to an external JS file from my HTML file. Whatever I do, the functions in that external JS file can not be called.

This is my HTML code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <script src="cookies.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            //some other JavaScript...
            function test() {
                extTest();
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button type="button" onclick="test();">Test</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

And this is my external JavaScript file:

```
function extTest() {
    alert("Hello world");
}
```

(I simplified both code blocks to contain only the necessary lines.)

So, whenever I click the button, the function extTest() is supposed to open a popup saying "Hello world". But extTest() is not called. Instead, I get a ReferenceError saying "extTest is not defined". The problem occurs in Firefox as well as Chrome and Edge.

Both files (HTML and JS) are in the same directory on my laptop. I tried linking to the JS file with a relative link (as shown in the code above), a relative link using . for current directory (./cookies.js), and an absolute link (/C:/...). I also tried putting the JS file in its own folder and linking to it, it didn't work.

I'd consider myself rather a beginner when it comes to JavaScript, but I already used external JS files and it worked. Do you guys have any idea where this error comes from? I mean, I could put all the code from the external file into the script in the HTML file, but I'm really curious why it's not working the other way.

Any hints are highly appreciated, thank you in advance.

Comment: Are these the actual contents of the files you are able to reproduce the issue with? I.e. Are you sure the issue isn't in the parts you omitted here? Do you get any other errors in the console? When looking at network requests, is your js file actually loaded?

Comment: Look at network tab of your browser (in developer mode) and make sure that the external javascript file is loaded before you call the function

Answer (score 0):

You can use just like this, you don't need to make another function inside because i suppose you make the js code in cookies.js

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <script src="cookies.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button type="button" onclick="extTest();">Test</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I called extTest from another function test because I wanted to place a breakpoint in the line and see if I can find out more from the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say initially it looks like you are declaring your function test but not invoking it. Try putting a line below that just has:
test ();

A question, if you similarly invoke your extTest function at the bottom of your external .js file, by which I mean again putting a line that says
extTest(); does it work as intended? If it doesn't, then there may be another issue at hand.